# Static Table View with dynamic text

Tags: swift, xcode, static, tableview

I have a static table view, but I want the last cell to say "Logout, (username here)"...can I even do that with a static table view?

The language I am using is Swift.

So far, I've tried to use cellForRowAtIndexPath and only have it return anything when the indexPath.row is the last cell. That doesn't work. Furthermore, it changes all of the other cells and, on top of that, they lose their segues to the other views...

Comment: When you say "static" table, I assume you're referring a table view for which you've changed the "Content Type" from "Dynamic Prototypes" to "Static Cells"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can update controls in static cells in `UITableViewController`'s `UITableView`. When you have a static table, you can just create `IBOutlet` references to the controls in the cells and update those outlets directly without use of any `UITableViewDataSource` methods. You can effectively just ignore the fact that it is a `UITableView` and treat these labels as if they were placed directly on the view in question. Just hook up the controls in the static cells to `IBOutlet` references in the view controller.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!  // in first cell
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!  // in second cell
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!  // in third cell

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label1.text = "foo"
        label2.text = "bar"
        label3.text = "baz"
    }

}
```